# What big data tools or approach to be used

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata

I have a central data store in AWS . I wanted to access multiple tables in that database and find patterns and predictions on those collection of data.

my tables have several transactional data like call details,marketing campaign details,contact information of people etc.

How to integrate all this data for a big data analysis to find the relationship and store them efficiently

I am confused whether to use Haddop or not, which architecture would be perfect

Comment: What do you mean by the "central data store" term?
What particular service do you use? RDS or Redshift?

Comment: aws ec2 nstance having a postgresSQL db

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way for you to start is to export tables you wish to analyze into a csv file and process it using Amazon Machine Learning.

The following guide describes entire process:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/tutorial.html